# Ruby - Set of inputs to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to have a dynamic set of inputs in a form, that start with just one, where you can add or remove them with add/delete buttons. Then upon submission of a form, it turns the values of the inputs into a hash then that hash into a string for storing. I really have no idea where to start. So any tips will be helpful.

If using javascript would help, I can go that route, but i'm not sure how to make the javascript and ruby talk.

Comment: You might want to research nested attributes; Ryan Bates does a [railscast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WJUaCI-SWg) on this. You might also be interested in the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use-case, there are a few options you might want to use.  Since you've tagged this with `rails`, I'm assuming you have access to JQuery.  Here's one (very simple) example of how you might go about adding fields to the page dynamically using it:

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lyvw0jm/

If you plan on storing these fields in one of your models, you may want to take a look at implementing [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 1):

As pretty much a common web thing (not Rails-specific), you would make the `name` value look like `some_name[]`.

So instead of having multiple inputs with different names like this:

```
<input type='text' id='my_input_1' name='my_input_1' value='string_1' />
<input type='text' id='my_input_2' name='my_input_2' value='string_2' />
<input type='text' id='my_input_3' name='my_input_3' value='string_3' />
```

...where on the server you get:

```
params :my_input_1 # 'string_1'
params :my_input_2 # 'string_2'
params :my_input_3 # 'string_3'
```

You would have:

```
<input type='text' id='my_input_1' name='my_inputs[]' value='string_1'  />
<input type='text' id='my_input_2' name='my_inputs[]' value='string_2'  />
<input type='text' id='my_input_3' name='my_inputs[]' value='string_3'  />
```

...where on the server you get:

```
params :my_inputs # ['string_1','string_2',string_3']
```

Comment: What kind of model field do you need for saving this to the database?

Comment: This could have a variety of applications, so it would depend on the application. Like, for example, the inputs could be used with a [jQueryUI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to add tags. The inputs would contain the `name` of a tag. Then, assuming that your object has a `has_many :tags` relationship, in the `create` and `update` actions you would do something like `object_params(:my_inputs).each{|name| @object.tags << Tag.find_by name: name} if object_params(:my_inputs).present?`.